# Django get_context_data() variable gets overwritten somewhere

Tags: python, django

This is simplified code example, but may be someone knows the reason the problem occurs without the exact copy of the code. So:

```
class FooView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'foo.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
    context = super(FooView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ...
    # here we get link to domain
    ...
    args = {'domain': domain}
    context.update(args)

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # here 'domain' has a value
    return context
```

The html template `foo.html` tries to access the 'domain' value with `{{ domain }}`, but it is None.

This happens only if I use 'domain' as the label. So if I change `domain` to `domain1` or `foo` - it works.

How is this possible? Is it possible `domain` name gots overwritten somehow, maybe some has a clue?

**EDIT** Change get_context_view --> get_context_data (mistype)

**EDIT2** My 'domain' context variable gets ovewritten by context_processor. All worked fine when function-based views were used. After switching to class-based views - the 'domain' started to get overwritten. May be get_context_data() is not *strong* enough? Is there any way to prevent context processor from overwriting the variable?

Comment: Could be a context processor. None of the built-in ones define `domain` but maybe you've defined a custom one?

Comment: You were right, it was a context processor that overwrites it.

Comment: Check the question description, please, have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TemplateView returns a [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/template-response/) which is known to overwrite the context passed to it with data from context processors. This is something that's [changing in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#priority-of-context-processors-for-templateresponse-brought-in-line-with-render) to be more consistent with `render`.

You should be able to fix this by overwriting `render_to_response` on your view with something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

...

class FooView(TemplateView):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return render(self.request, self.get_template_names()[0], context)
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. You solution worked like a charm. This is the first time I have encountered this problem.. dunno how I would find the answer without kind people from StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible if some or template tags of context processors injects `domain` variable into context.

Are you sure than method is called `get_context_view`? Imho it should be `get_context_data`.

Comment: My bad, get_context_data it is.

Comment: 'domain' gets overwritten by context_processor. Is get_context_data() not "strong" enough to prevent this?

Comment: @tom provided the answer.